# Use ServiceStack Typescript client for non-servicestack server

Tags: typescript, servicestack

I've been using ServiceStack since v3 but been dragged away from C# for a while now, digging into node, and typescript recently as a middle ground :)

So now I've got this project where I need to consume this massive REST API built upon Tastypie, I thought first of what was new on ServiceStack side of things and found this [Typescript client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/servicestack-client).

The problem is how to use it without the "Add a ServiceStack reference..." wizard.

What I'd like to do is write a converter from Tastypie documentation to ServiceStack dtos, Requests and responses, and then use the ServiceStack client with those dtos.
I'm a bit lost between the typescript definition only and the strongly type client and I can't find any full example of generated Typescript DTOs.

Is there any way to have at least routing (with params), typed requests and responses ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a [TypeScript ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/TypeScript-Add-ServiceStack-Reference) is the same as any other [Add ServiceStack Reference](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Add-ServiceStack-Reference) language where you just right-click the location where you want the DTOs and go to `Add > TypeScript Reference...` in the context menu then enter the **BaseUrl** to a **remote ServiceStack Instance** in the dialog. Clicking **OK** then adds the generated TypeScript DTOs to your project with the filename specified. The [ServiceStackVS](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS) VS.NET Extension enables Add ServiceStack Reference support in VS.NET whilst the [ServiceStackIDEA plugin](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/TypeScript-Add-ServiceStack-Reference#servicestackidea-plugin) adds support for JetBrains IDEs, whilst http://gistlyn.com/add-servicestack-reference shows how you can add a ServiceStack Reference in [Gistlyn](http://gistlyn.com/) an online C# Gist IDE which lets you run C# scripts with just a browser.

You can **only** generate Typed DTOs **for a remote ServiceStack instance** which is transformed from your C# DTOs and designed to work with ServiceStack's message-based APIs and pre-defined routes. It's not something you can use to consume a 3rd Party (non-ServiceStack) API with. If you just wanted the generated DTO Types you'd need to create a blank ServiceStack project with C# DTOs matching the 3rd Party API and empty Service implementations (e.g. throwing NotImplementedExceptions), then you can access the TypeScript DTOs from `/types/typescript` route.

Comment: Mythz you'll always amaze me with your answers.. Ok so one way of using ServiceStack typescript client for a 3rd Party REST API server would be to create a c# project, generate DTOs from API doc and then run a dumb server and get the TypeScript DTOs from it... can't I try to generate those Typescript DTOs straight from the Tastypie doc ?
I'm just exploring here, basically trying to do like in C# : using ServiceStack client and DTO based architecture to consume 3rdParty APIs..

Comment: @baramuse Seems like you want to call 3rd Party API using their Tastypie docs, so I don't see where you would use ServiceStack for here? ServiceStack generates Typed DTOs in different languages for **calling ServiceStack Services**, if you're not calling a ServiceStack Service then I'd just be using whatever their recommendation is for calling their 3rd Party API. The best you can do is create a blank ServiceStack project with C# DTOs in the same shape as the 3rd Party API which will let you generate TypeScript DTOs, but you'd still need to handle constructing 3rd party Routes, etc.

Comment: it's just that i used to use ServiceStack.Client as my default REST API client in C# (over RESTSharp for example) because I liked the way I only had to define POCO DTOs to describe Requests, Responses and Routes.
I thought I could do the same with the ServiceStack Typescript client. i guess I'll have to write one then :)